# HTML form input to mysql TIME

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am having an add/edit form to update and add to database, and I was not sure what the best way is to input TIME type (HH:MM:SS). Should I use multiple html text inputs for HH, MM, SS?
if so, is there a function that prepares the string for database input?

Basically what I'm trying to input is how many hours, minutes, seconds a specific task took to finish.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

I'm designing a website using Codeigniter (PHP).

Thanks

Let me go ahead and clarify what needs to happen a bit more...
The user is required to enter data specific to sports more in particular to a players minutes and seconds played. I'm thinking of maybe simplifying it to only minutes. Perhaps this way input is only 1 thing. Then again my question is, what method would work to convert this "minute number" to the correct MYSQL TIME format?

Comment: It seems a little odd to have a user type a time in seconds into an HTML form. You said you want to input how long a specific task took to finish--how is the task run? Can the task or the framework that runs it compute this time and send it to your php server instead of making the user type it in?

Comment: Please read the last bit.. I added some info for better understanding. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searched for some alternatives and solutions and I came up with this:

```
$min = 60;
$time[] = floor($min/60);
$time[] = $min%60;
```

And I used the following to convert to MySQL TIME format

```
INSERT INTO table (min) VALUES (MAKETIME($time[0], $time[1], 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a helper to do something similar in an app I'm working on. Mine generates three dropdowns, hh, mm and am/pm, by calling built in form_dropdown helper. Once I get the data from the drop downs, I convert it 24hr format and then I just concatenate the strings into the right format for MySQL. Since it's a helper I can just call it from any view using  `form_time()`. I can post it here if you think it would help to see it.

Dana

Answer (score 0):

> just use now() function, if your DB is
>   MYSQL is you want to save the current
>   time
>
> e.g:
>
> ```
> UPDATE tbl SET timemodified = NOW()
> ```
>
> and make sure that timemodified has a
>   type of "time"

Ow sory miss that point. uhm maybe you need to have a start time in your DB, then after he/.she is finish his/her task. you must query on the DB the start time subtract it to the end time(your current time) then the result would be the time he/she performed the task

Comment: You missed the point; the input is coming from a form and moleculezz is asking for advice on how to design that part of the form and how to join the parts of the time together for the insert/update in a codeigniter/php friendly way.

Answer (score 0):

this checks for 2 numbers, then a ":" then 2 numbers, then a ":", then finally 2 numbers again:

```
$cleanTime = preg_match( '/(\d\d)\:(\d\d)\:(\d\d)/', $_POST[ 'NAME_OF_TIME_INPUT' ] );
if( !$cleanTime ){ /* ... error ... */ }
```

don't be scared of all the slashes, haha (I was at first when I used regexps).

replace `NAME_OF_TIME_INPUT` with the content of the `name` attribute on the `<input` on the `<form` page

i.e. if `<input name="coolinput" />` then use `$_POST[ 'coolinput' ]`

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the eternal struggles of (web) UI design, how to input time without driving the users nuts. What works for your specific case is something only you can decide, because it depends on the exact format/circumstances you need and your target audience.

As general guidelines I'd say:

- **Don't** do a free-form text field that requires a certain format, e.g. "Enter time (HH:MM:SS)", because it's too easy to mess up and will deny the users input or mess up the time if you do no validation.
- Try to avoid [0-23] [0-59] [0-59] dropdowns, since they can be quite a pain (click, scroll, click, click, scroll, click, click, scroll, click).

If ease of use is a high priority, as would be the case for public websites, maybe a Javascript enhanced timepicker is a good idea. Try not to use anything too fancy that nobody gets though (like dragging the hands on a clock).

A free-form, free-format text field might be the best idea. The user can just type in "3pm", "16:34" or "midnight". You may need to provide examples to get users started, otherwise they may feel lost. You can run this through `strtotime` on your end, but you may need to fill in the blanks and do a lot of validation.

Three short text fields may be a good idea if your audience is very keyboard focused and can be expected to tab through them in rapid order.

As for formatting it for SQL, however you receive the time input from the user, you should assemble it to a UNIX timestamp and format that timestamp for SQL:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

Comment: You have a point here. This is the reason I posted the question, because I was worried the users might get confused.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue with working with the html time input. However, I've managed to work around it with a PHP function.

What the function does is translate the time into a format the MYSQL DATETIME datatype can understand.

Of course you will need to enter the date somehow, but I'll leave that up to you.

functions.php

```
function convertHtmlTime($date,$time){
        $newDate = date($date);
        $newTime = date($time);
        $datetime = new DateTime($newDate.$newTime);
        return date_format($datetime, 'YmdHis');
}
```

test.php

```
$date="2007-02-16";
$time="23:59";
echo convertHtmlTime($date,$time);
```

Results:

20070216235900